# Integer Type && Null in java

Tags: java

I have a class such as :

```
class node 
{
    Integer id ; 
    double lon;
    double lat ; 
    ..... 
}
```

There is a method in other class takes arguments from node class , and do some operation by them .... 
in this method , there is condition like (node1.getId == node2.getId) ...

Now I need to give this method node1 , node2 argument where the id of node1 = null .. 
when it compares between  (node1.getId == node2.getId) , NullpointerException is thrown ...

Is there an  integer type in Java that I can compare objects of it with null ?? like "int? " in C# ..

Comment: You can compare `Integer` with null, just not `int`.

Comment: The expression node1.getId() == node2.getId() only throws a NullPointerException if node1 == null or node2 == null. I suggest you use a debugger to debug you problem, it would should you want is null. If you compare two Integer values with == you will not get an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing like the `?`. If there is a possibility for `null`, you have to test for it.

So,

```
if (node1 == null || node2 == null) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: you mean node1.getId() ... 
I try this with my project last time , but it doesn't work ... 

but now ,I notic that getId() return int not Integer although Id is Integer ... 
when I change the returned type of getId() to Integer it works .. 

thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Further information on what probably happened.

From your error, I'm guessing your previous getter was:

```
public int getId() {
    return id; //Integer, needs to be converted
}
```

Java made the job for you to change the Integer in int, and what was actually called was:

```
public int getId() {
    return id.intValue(); //Get the actual "int" value from the object
}
```

This is why calling this method with a null id threw a NullPointException, even before you could get the value. Because a method was called on this id, before you could access it.

This is a frequent trap happening since they allowed such transparent conversion from Integer to int and opposite. It's convenient, but hard to diagnose if you don't know what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I supose you can use the `Integer` class instead of the int type. Here's an example:

```
public class myClass {
  Integer id;
  public myClass() {
     // A constructor with no arguments
     id = null;
  }
  public void setId(int val) {
     id = new Integer(val);
  }
  public Integer getId() {
     return Id;
  }
}
```

The reference for the `Integer` class is here: http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Notice that the `getId` method returns an `Integer` object, which can be a null object. Thus, it is possible to evaluate something like `if(getId()==null) {...}`

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks , it works when I change The return value of getInt() into Integer .. Thanks for your answer :)